# What is the correct way to assign an const unsigned char* data into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sqlite

I have the following code :

```
sqlite *sql = new sqlite; // create a new sqlite object.
const char *dbFile = "database.db"; // sqlite database file.

sql->open(dbFile);  // open the connection.
sql->query("SELECT * FROM categories"); // make a query.
int numRows = sql->numRows(); // get the number of rows.
const unsigned char *result[numRows]; // an array to store data that will be brought in from the database.
int index = 0; // counter

while(sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE){
    // store the data into an array
    result[index] = sql->getValue("name");
    index++;

    // print the data directly without storing in an array
    cout << sql->getValue("name") << endl;
}
sql->close();

// print the content of the `result` array.
for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){
    cout << result[i] << endl;
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

**Notice:**

The method `sql->getValue("name");` return `const unsigned char*` data.

As you seen in the result image, why when print the data directly, appear without problems, while when print the same data stored in the array does not appear ?

---

### The solution

Firstly: I thank everyone who contributed(by comment or answer) to helping me to reach to a solution for my problem.
their answers really deserve the best answer.

```
sqlite *sql = new sqlite;
const char *dbFile = "database.db";
sql->open(dbFile);
sql->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
int numRows = sql->numRows();
char **result = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * numRows);
int index = 0;

while(sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE){
    result[index] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * CHAR_MAX);
    strcpy(result[index], reinterpret_cast<const char*> (sql->getValue("name")));
    index++;

    cout << sql->getValue("name") << endl;
}
cout << "\n\n" << endl;
sql->close();

for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){
    cout << *(result+i) << endl;
}
```

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: The `const unsigned char *result[numRows]` is a g++ extension. Is your intention to have standard C++ code?

Comment: Re the question, most likely the pointer you get from `sql->getValue` is only valid until the next call. Why don't you just copy the text. You can simply use a `vector<string>`, since you're using C++ u now.

Comment: I wonder if the pointer returned by `sql->geValue()` is a temporary pointer that gets overwritten in the next function call. I would try `result[index] = strdup(sql->getValue("name"));`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks, not g++ extension, and yes, I want a standard c++ code. there is another way away from `vector` and so on.

Comment: @RSahu: Thanks, but when use `strdup` shows an error `invalid conversion from const unsigned char* to const char*`.

Comment: @LionKing - `sqlite *sql = new sqlite; // create a new sqlite object.`  C++ is not Java.  All you need is this: `sqlite sql;`

Comment: @LionKing, you can use `strdup(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(sql->getValue("name")))`.

Comment: Your array is simply pointing into the data that is still in the returned result set. You then close the result set before trying to access its data via the array. You need to copy the data or use it directly from the result set before you close it.

Comment: I think just a force cast will do: `strdup( (char const*)(sql->getValue("name")))`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: thank you, but I did that to create dynamic object to reserve into the heap memory not into stack, and will be deleted after finished.

Comment: @LionKing - All you did was call the allocator for no real reason that I see, plus you open yourself up for a memory leak.  If any function happens to throw an exception, you can't `delete` what you allocated.

Comment: @RSahu: I already heard that the `reinterpret_cast` is not safe. also I have doing the conversion as you mentioned (char const*), but there is an error `invalid conversion from char* to const unsigned char*`

Comment: @Galik: thank you, but I think your words not clear enough for me, `still in the returned result set`, `You then close the result set before trying to access its data via the array`, `You need to copy the data or use it directly from the result set before you close it.`

Comment: Several people have told you that you've made an error by copying a pointer instead of the pointed-at data; and you've replied that you don't understand what they're talking about or that there's a distinction.  There isn't really a nice way to say this, so please take it as advice and not an insult:  pointers are fundamental to C and C++, and while they can be hard to understand ( http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html ) there is no way to be productive in C or C++ without learning the distinction between a pointer and the data a pointer points at.

Comment: Pointers are a common source of confusion and bugs, so you're in good company.  But you will be fundamentally limited until you learn how they work.

Comment: Regarding the edit:  why are you trying to make the destination buffer `const`?  There are two reasons you're getting the error message from the compiler about needing a cast:  (1) your source type is `char*` while your destination is `unsigned char*` (a perfectly fine reason for a cast); and (2) your source pointer type points at data that is not `const`, but your destination pointer type points at data that is, i.e., a buffer that you told the compiler to not allow you to change.

Comment: @MaxLybbert: Thank you, I benefited a lot from your words.

Comment: I forgot to finish my comment on the cast:  casting `char*` to `unsigned char*` is trivial, and you may not even need a cast to copy data from a `char*` to `unsigned char*`.  But copying from `char*` to `const unsigned char*` is impossible because of the `const`.

Comment: @MaxLybbert: I have some confusion about `const char*` and `char*`. what is the difference between them?, and when can I use each one?

Comment: There are really two meanings to `const`.  The one you most often run into is essentially "const for this function/method/scope only," i.e., "I want the compiler to complain if I try to modify this object in this scope."  It's legal to cast away this kind of `const` and modify the object, but doing so is highly discouraged.  The other meaning is "I created an object that must be immutable from the moment it's initialized to the moment it's destroyed."  It's legal to cast away this kind of `const`, but it's undefined behavior to actually modify the object.  You have the second form of `const`.

Comment: (There's an additional issue with pointers:  is the pointer `const` or the thing being pointed at `const`?).  So, in your case, you have a buffer that you need to copy data into, but since the buffer's data is declared as `const`, copying into it is undefined.  That makes the buffer useless.  `const` is a great thing ( https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness ), but you have to know what you're working for and why.  In this case, it's simply causing trouble.

Comment: The reason you're confused, btw, is that string literals are `const char*` (or `const char[]`), e.g., `const char[] foo = "FOO";`.  This wasn't always the case ( http://yarchive.net/comp/string_literals.html ).  String literals are also null-terminated C-style strings, **but** null-terminated C-style strings don't have to be `const`.  They can't be `const` if you plan to change the contents; and in your case you need to change the contents:  `char* bar = malloc(strlen(foo)); strcpy(bar, foo);`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, replace this original code:

```
const unsigned char *result[numRows]; // an array to store data that will be brought in from the database.
int index = 0; // counter

while(sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE){
    // store the data into an array
    result[index] = sql->getValue("name");
    index++;
}
```

with this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::string; using std::vector;
    ⋮

vector<string> result;
while( sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE )
{
    result.emplace_back( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(
        sql->getValue("name")
        ) );
}
```

And also replace the `printf` with `cout <<`, or else, in the `printf` call replace `result[i]` with `result[i].c_str()`.

All assuming that the original code works.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

---

**Addendum:**

You most recent code-that-doesn't-compile,

```
const unsigned char **result = (const unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(const unsigned char*) * numRows);
int index = 0;
while(sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE){
    result[index] = (const unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(const unsigned char*) * CHAR_MAX);
    strcpy(result[index], sql->getValue("name"));
    index++;

    cout << sql->getValue("name") << endl;
}
```

… can be expressed in C-style C++ as

```
char** result = new char*[numRows]();
int index = 0;
while( sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE )
{
    assert( index < numRows );
    char const* const s = reinterpret_cast<char*>( sql->getValue( "name" ) );
    result[index] = new char[1 + strlen( s )];
    strcpy( result[index], s );
    cout << s << endl;
    ++index;
}
```

Again assuming that the original code worked.

Disclaimer: Again, the code has not been touched by a compiler. Also, readers should note that using `new` directly, while that improves on using `malloc`, is ungood practice. Good practice would be to use `std::vector` and `std::string`, as I advised first of all.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I don't want to use `vector` and so on, also `emplace_back` is c++11, and I still do not use c++11. is there are no any other ways except this way ?

Comment: You can use C++03 `push_back` in this case. Of course there are other ways, including implementing your own `vector`. But since the standard library provides it it would be technically silly not to use it.

Comment: Why worked with the string type ? and why can't do that by convert to `const char*` directly, then insert into array like I did ?, for example why can't do the following : `const char* result[numRows];
    while(sql->fetch() != SQLITE_DONE){
        result[index] = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sql->getValue("name"));
        index++;
    }`

Comment: @LionKing: Storing the pointers is not enough. The data that those pointers point to (if they are indeed distinct pointers) will be gone as soon as you close the connection, and perhaps already at the next call of `getValue`. You need to copy the data, hence `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'm sorry I'm still don't understand the idea, and what did you mean `storing the pointers is not enough`?

Comment: @LionKing: I have to speculate about your background here, and I'm guessing Java or C#, or maybe Python. In those languages, when you have a reference to something, that something lives on as long as you hold the reference. Not so in C++ with pointers. A pointer doesn't keep the pointed to object alive. When the pointee gets destroyed (or its storage is reused), then the pointer is just -- so much junk. Called a *dangling pointer*. You need to copy what it points at, not the pointer itself. You can use `strcpy` to a buffer, or assignment or initialization of a `std::string`.

Comment: regarding your guess, unfortunately not correct. I have used another way which is copy the text which the pointer pointed to and store the text into a dynamic memory, but there is an error, I have been updated my question. please see my updates to see my new code and the error .

Comment: Well that's 2 issues. First, you can't have an originally `const` buffer. The Holy Standard goes to pains to point out that it's Undefined Behavior to modify it even when it's allocated dynamically. The second issue is the same as before, that you need to `reinterpret_cast` the result pointer from `unsigned char*` to the `char*` formal argument type of `strcpy`; and also use the plain `char` type for the result buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started looking at Sqlite myself so I happen to have some code I knocked up that I have extracted to give as an exampe. This is not supposed to be particularly *performant* just to get the job done.

It also includes code to get the SQL `REGEXP` function working.

The idea is to add elements to a data structure during the `select callback`. The data structure is a `std::vector` of `std::map`. The `std::map` being the table's colum data mapped from the column names and the `std::vector` containing the rows of columns:

```
#include <map>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

#include <sqlite3.h>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> result;
typedef std::vector<result> result_vec;

#define log(msg) std::cout << msg << std::endl

static int select_callback(void* user, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    result_vec& v = *static_cast<result_vec*>(user);
    result r;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        if(argv[i])
            r.emplace(azColName[i], argv[i]);
    v.emplace_back(std::move(r));
    return 0;
}

static void regexp_callback(sqlite3_context* context, int argc,
    sqlite3_value** argv)
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        const char* pattern = (const char*) sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
        const char* value = (const char*) sqlite3_value_text(argv[1]);

        if(pattern && value)
        {
            std::string s = value;
            std::regex r(pattern, std::regex::icase);
            std::smatch m;
            if(std::regex_search(s, m, r))
                count = m.size();
        }
    }
    sqlite3_result_int(context, (int) count);
}

sqlite3* open(const std::string& name)
{
    sqlite3* db;
    if(sqlite3_open(name.c_str(), &db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        log("ERROR: opening db: " << name);
        log("ERROR: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return nullptr;
    }
    sqlite3_create_function_v2(db, "REGEXP", 2, SQLITE_ANY, 0, regexp_callback, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    return db;
}

bool select(sqlite3* db, const std::string& sql, result_vec& v)
{
    char* error = 0;
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), select_callback, &v, &error) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        log("ERROR: " << error);
        log("ERROR: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        log("  SQL: " << sql);
        sqlite3_free(error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    sqlite3* db = open("mydatabase.db");

    if(db)
    {
        result_vec results;

        if(!select(db, "select * from mytable", results))
            return 1;

        for(auto&& row: results)
            for(auto&& col: row)
                std::cout << col.first << ": " << col.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I just read that you are not looking to use `std::vector` or **C++11** features so this answer is not what you are looking for (although it may still be of use to you). However I will leave it for other people who may google this question.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to write that code. but as I said previously, I don't want to use `c++11`, `vector` and so on. I want the code to be simple, and not complex as much as I can.

Comment: @LionKing By and large, using `std::vector` (which is not a C++11 feature) and C++11 features will make your code simpler; they handle a lot of details for you.  You can handle those details yourself, but you'll have to write more code to do so, which will make your code more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're assigning a pointer rather than copying the string. This is an important distinction.

Assigning the pointer doesn't "store the data" as your comment suggests, it simply copies the pointer. SQLite discards the data after it's done with the record, so its buffers are free to use with another record. By the time you go to print out the string, the pointer is no longer valid.

In order to retain the string for later printing you'll need to copy the string to your own buffer.

This means you'll need to allocate buffer space for the string, copy the string, and then free the space when you're done with it.

It sounds like you want to avoid using C++ features, so you'll want to look at `malloc()`, `free()`, and `strncpy()` to accomplish your task. Otherwise, if you wanted to use the C++ STL `String` class, that would solve your problem nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation, I have done what you said, but the result is an error `invalid conversion from const unsigned char* to char*`. look at my question again(bottom part) to see the code which was used.

Comment: I see you have a cast in the `strncpy()` call -- did that solve your problem? Also, it's a really good idea to use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()` -- you can use your `CHAR_MAX` constant for the `size_t` argument.

Comment: Thank you for because you had helped me, Yes my problem solved, and also thanks for your advice.